# Odd no such column error SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm only beginning to learn SQL with `SQLite3` so this question probably has a clear answer, which I just can't think of. I have a table called Books, which has the columns: name, author and price. When I type e.g. `select name, price from Books where author = "A";` in sqlite3, it works just fine. However, when I make a .sql file with the following:

```
 SELECT name, price
 FROM Books
 WHERE author = "A";`
```

and read the file in the same database, it reads

```
 'Error: near line 1: no such column: "A"'
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I have also tried the same with single quotes (i.e. 'A') but it still gives the same error:

```
Error: near line 1: no such column: 'A'
```

Comment: `" "` **double-quotes** used for identifiers and `''` **single-quotes** used for string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I was using Mac's TextEdit program to write the SQL queries and it uses so called "smart quotes", which are not recognized as quotes by SQL. So I just changed the smart quote-setting off and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes `"A"` are used as identifiers; you want to use single quotes `'A'` for string literals. See the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) for more information.

`SELECT name, price FROM Books WHERE author = 'A'`;

The reason it worked in the first example is probably due to this:

> If a keyword in double quotes (ex: "key" or "glob") is used in a
>   context where it cannot be resolved to an identifier but where a
>   string literal is allowed, then the token is understood to be a string
>   literal instead of an identifier.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned it in the question, but it doesn't work with single quotes either. It reads "Error: near line 1: no such column: 'A'"

Comment: @Mikke.e How are you executing the SQLite query? I can't recreate this problem and the syntax should be fine. Since the error indicates line 1 I'm guessing that you might be executing the sql-code as three separate lines instead of one.